# Elastic Search query analyzing

Tags: elasticsearch, analyzer

I want to see all the tokens is generated from 'match' text

I am wondering to know is there any specific file or capability to show details of query executing in elastic search or another way to see what is generated as a sequence of tokens when I am using 'match level' queries?

Comment: There is no such thing. What is a "token"?

Comment: @AndreiStefan Tokens generated by tokenizer I mean. I want to see the sequence of tokens which are generated and used in the search. ELS 2.1.1

Comment: @AndreiStefan I think I found a way to see analyser result by using _analayze endpoint

Comment: Oh, the terms generated. Then yes, the `_analyze` API.

Answer (score 0):

I did not use the log file to see which tokens are generated in the time of 'match' operation. Instead, I used _analayze endpoint.

Better to say if you want to use analyser of the specific index (in the case of different indices that each of them using its own customised analyser) put the name of the index in the URL:

```
POST /index_name/_analyze
{
  "text" : "1174HHA8285M360"
}
```

This will use the default analyser defined in that index. And if we have more than one analyser in one index we can specify it in the query just as follow:

```
POST /index_name/_analyze
{
  "text" : "1174HHA8285M360",
  "analyzer" : "analyser_name" 
}
```